# Como suavizar a fonte com CSS no Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-font-face

Estou com um problema de fonte "craquelado" no Chrome, ou seja, parece que as pontas ficam pixelizadas.

Para ajudar, estou postando duas imagens

**IE**:

[image: Imagem no IE]

**Chrome**:

[image: Imagem no Chrome]

O meu CSS que chama a fonte:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Helvetica-nw";
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNw_.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
    url('../fonts/HelveticaNw_.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNw_.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Alguem sabe como fazer com que minha fonte dê para visualizar corretamente no Chrome?

Comment: Antigamente tinha site que informava: Este site é melhor visualizado em navegadores Internet Explorer versão 6 e Site melhor visualizado em resolução 800x600 ou superior com plugin Flash ... :)

Comment: A [resposta em Inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome) é excelente.

Comment: Tenta acrescentar -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Comment: Com -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; e -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; não dá, como indicado no outro stackoverflow, não muda em nada, a solução que encontrei foi usar o -webkit-text-stroke: 0.6px; que vou ter que definir para cada parte que a fonte for um tamanho diferente, mas pelo menos melhora

Comment: na realidade com  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.6px; não parece ter ficado certo

Answer (score 4):

O `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` na verdade é uma técnica criada para o navegador Safari para telas de retina em computadores Mac (sistema OS X)

Tanto que a versão desta propriedade para firefox é `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;` <sup>(fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth)</sup>

> **Relacionado:** [Entendendo a diferença do antialias tradicional para o ClearType](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124282/3635)

Não existe nenhuma propriedade padronizada para isto especificamente, mas conforme este repositório https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1846552 existem algumas técnicas que pode tentar (*sem garantia*):

### Propriedade `font-smooth: always`:

Ainda não é suportando por nenhum navegador, esta propriedade é o que basicamente vai substituir o `-webkit-font-smoothing` e `-moz-osx-font-smoothing`

```css
.examplo {
    font-smooth: always;
    font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="examplo">
 Olá, Mundo! Hello World!
</div>
```

### Propriedade `text-rendering`

Esta propriedade talvez possa vir a ajudar, mas também pode afetar, já que o uso dela não é bem para o que deseja, todavia os valores da propriedade são:

- `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;`
- `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`
- `text-rendering: geometricPrecision;`

### Propriedade `transform: rotate()`:

Isto causa um "tilt" no CSS que "ajusta a fonte"

```css
.examplo {
    transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
    font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="examplo">
 Olá, Mundo! Hello World!
</div>
```

### Propriedade `text-shadow`:

Conforme os testes para *Windows* especificamente este foi o que teve melhor resultado, é necessário ajustar a mesma cor e/ou tamanho que a fonte usa

```css
.examplo {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);/*a cor deve ser a mesma da fonte, ajuste a opacidade como desejar*/
    font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="examplo">
 Olá, Mundo! Hello World!
</div>
```

O grupo/pessoa que mantém o repositório criou uma exemplo para facilitar com jQuery, mas isto obrigará a importar *jQuery* somente para um "efeito", claro que se usa jQuery estará bem, mas caso contrário é melhor evitar, então refiz em um exemplo simples:

```
function getStyle(elem, prop)
{
    if (elem.currentStyle) { //IE8
        return elem.currentStyle[prop];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {//Navegadores modernos
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    }
}

function smoothByShadow(elem)
{
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') == -1) {
        return;
    }

    var color = getStyle(elem, "color");

    if (color.search('rgb') != -1) {
        var rgba = color.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);

        elem.style.textShadow = "0 0 1px rgba(" + rgba[1] + "," + rgba[2] + "," + rgba[3] + ",1)";
    }
}
```

Para aplicar em um elemento basta usar, exemplo aplicado em todos sub-titulos:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

for (var i = h1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    smoothByShadow(h1[i]);
}
```

Se não tiver o efeito desejado talvez tenha que ajustar o tamanho da fonte:

```
function smoothByShadow(elem)
{
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') == -1) {
        return;
    }

    var color = getStyle(elem, "color"),
        size = getStyle(elem, "font-size");

    if (color.search('rgb') != -1) {
        var rgba = color.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);

        var fsize = size.match(/(\d+)px/);

        elem.style.textShadow = "0 0 " + (fsize[1] / 15) + "px rgba(" + rgba[1] + "," + rgba[2] + "," + rgba[3] + ",0.3)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente nenhuma dessas funcionou comigo, achei uma fonte boa e que parece não sofrer tanto com essas alterações de navegador, segue o link para quem quiser no futuro https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/ostrich-sans

Comment: Ainda estou desenvolvendo essa, da uma olhada como a fonte fica http://www.bluanime.com/v2/navegar

Comment: Sim to tentando com windows, já testei em 1366 x 768 e 1920 x 1080 ... só no chrome a fonte fica zoada

Comment: @LeoLetto chrome 64bit? Por favor informe se é LED ou LCD ou outro e informe o tamanho do monitor, tipo 17" (polegadas).

Comment: LED, 64bit, 17"

Comment: Em fontes pequenas da um efeito legal, mas em fontes maiores como o titulo h2 em negrito grande fica mais visível, webkit avançado em tantas coisas, e não consegue renderizar textos direito

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49492/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-leo-letto).

Answer (score 1):

Em alguns casos quando isso acontece, resolvo com isso:

```
   body {   
        /* CSS3*/
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
```

Comment: Outra solução, sería você adicionar: text-shadow: 0.01em 0.01em 0.01em black; 
Não esqueça de substituir o black pela sua cor da fonte.

Comment: vou tentar novamente do text-shadow, só que tenho que configurar um valo diferente para cada tamanho... já o -webkit-font-smoothing: já tentei, mas não dá diferença, não sei se o Chrome retirou esse suporte

Answer (score 1):

A verdade é o pessoal do Google retirou o suporte do `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` só pra irritar os programadores. `=(`

Eles devem achar que isso prejudica o desempenho do navegador.

No IE e Firefox as fontes ficam melhores pois eles usam um motor de renderização de fontes "por fora", enquanto o Chrome usa o fornecido pelo Windows, chamado ClearType.

O jeito é se contentar com gambiarras como essa:

```
body { 
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #333;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2px;
}
```

Mas como nada fica 100%, eu prefiro desistir e deixar o padrão mesmo.

Comment: A Google vai implementar o DirectWrite aparentemente, que corrige o problema, mas eu já passei com problemas de visualizações em algumas páginas com ele ativado, como o Facebook, não sei se mais alguem passou por isso depois de ativar ele no chrome://flags

Comment: @braulio_holtz Ativei o DirectWrite aqui há uma melhora perceptível. Possivelmente logo não precisaremos mais de gambiarras.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar algumas técnicas e classes novas do CSS3

Primeiro vou começar com a técnica do `Filter:Blur()`, pelo fato de ninguém ter mencionando ainda. *(Não funciona no IE apenas Edge)*

Aqui estão os resultados com o Filtro. Parece que algumas `font-family`tem um resultado melhor ou pior, cabe a você avaliar se é a melhor técnica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare no **"e"** no **"t"** e no **"u"** minúsculo como é nítido o resultado 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais um exemplo com e sem o filtro em uma fonte com péssima renderização. ***O filter está no limite, ai vai do bom senso.***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os estilos de filtro precisam de *aceleração de hardwares*, mas parece que mesmo com o *Blur* acentuado consome muito pouco recurso na hora do render e o FPS é praticamente igual, no Chrome pelo menos...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que quiser fazer uns testes aqui está o Snipper do teste que fiz com `filter:blur()`

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 4.25rem;
    font-family: cursive;
    filter: blur(0.35px);
}
h1:nth-child(1) {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
h1:nth-child(2){
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
h1:nth-child(3){
    font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Texto Blur1</h1>
<h1>Texto Blur2</h1>
<h1>Texto Blur3</h1>
<h1>Texto Blur4</h1>
```

---

**Técnicas já citadas e conhecidas.**

Você pode colocar um `text-shadow` muito suave, apenas para fazer um efeito de Smooth na font. Veja abaixo no caso coloquei na cor branca que é a cor da sua font.

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.004);
```

O mesmo principio pode ser usado com `-webkit-text-stroke` para todos os Browsers

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.45px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
```

Fonte de referência: https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-text-stroke

Também é possível usar algumas classes CSS

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;  /* não funciona no IE e Edge */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* apenas para Mac OS X/macOS */
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; /* apenas para Mac OS X/macOS */
font-smooth: always; /* Non-standard */
```

**optimizeLegibility:**
O navegador prioriza legibilidade sobre a velocidade de renderização e precisão geométrica. Essa propriedade habilita o kerning e ligatures opcionais.

**font-smoothing *(Non-standard)*:** Aplica um anti-aliasing no contorno da fonte

*Fonte para vc dar uma pesquisada:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering

**Font-smoothing:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth