# Problema com web fonts em vários navegadores

Tags: css

Estou usando a font **Open Sans** do google e a **font Awesome**, mas os resultados são diferentes em alguns navegadores, só ficando "perfeito" no firefox, ex:

[image: Navegadores com problemas]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Não funcionou .

Comment: Só de curiosidade, como você determina que exibição correta seja a do Firefox, e não do resto dos browsers? Pela imagem, o que me parece é que o FF não está aplicando _cleartype_, mas usando antialias monocromático.

Comment: @Bacco Oque ele quer é justamente que a fonte fique suavizada em todos os browsers. Esta é uma dúvida comum, inclusive minha.

Comment: @user3386417 Tente utilizando a solução [desta resposta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17090/7261).

Comment: Já vi esse tbm, não resolveu :/