# Fonte serrilhada Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-font-face

Como resolver este problema no Firefox em relação a fontes ? 
Infelizmente no Chrome fica suave e no Firefox serrilhado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não está sendo perfeccionista demais? Eu nem diria que o problema é do Firefox, e sim de resolução. Se abrir o site num smartphone, independente se no Chrome ou Firefox, a fonte ficará perfeita, já que a resolução seria "maior" no celular. O usuário final nem vai reparar nesse serrilhado. E outra, a forma de renderizar fonte no Chrome é diferente do Firefox, então não espere resultados iguais em tecnologias diferentes. "Anti-Aliasing" é uma gambi criada para compensar a baixa resolução. Abraço.

Comment: O font-smooth, para funcionar, só para sistema operacional Mac OSX: http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-smooth

Comment: Só pra constar, o "Antialiasing" tradicional é tecnologia obsoleta. Hoje se usa subpixel, considerando que praticamente todo mundo usa LCD. (chamado de Cleartype no windows). No screenshot está evidente que o Firefox está fazendo Antialias tradicional, e o Chrome subpixel, por isso a diferença. Pode ser um problema de configuração ou implementação. (pra quem não sabe o que é, basta ampliar a imagem da postagem e ver a diferença entre os dois lados. O Antialias é P&B, o cleartype é colorido)

Answer (score 5):

### Entendendo a diferença do *antialias* tradicional para o *ClearType*

Veja sua imagem ampliada:

<kbd>[image: ampliacao do screenshot]</kbd>

Note que a imagem da direita tem pixels coloridos. Como o LCD não é formado por *pixels* de todas as cores, mas sim pequenos retângulos vermelhos, verde e azuis um do lado do outro, esta diferença de posição é usada para simular mais pixels horizontais (a maior parte dos LCDs para monitores é organizada horizontalmente).

O Antialias, por sua vez, faz apenas uma interpolação de *pixel* inteiro, tendo 3 vezes menos resolução que *ClearType* (entretanto, não fica com artefatos coloridos nas letras).

### Habilitando ClearType no FireFox:

O FireFox por padrão usa Antialias, em vez do ClearType (*subpixel rendering*).

Esta extensão permite você habilitar o recurso:

> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/

Se preferir, pode digitar `about:config` no campo de endereços e configurar manualmente as opções de ClearType, que fazem parte deste grupo:

```
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params
```

Porém, está sujeito a bagunçar mais o navegador do que resolver o problema.

Answer (score 4):

É comum, que alguns browsers não exibam a fonte com anti-aliasing.

Conheço 3 alternativas com CSS3. Declarações:

`transform: rotate (-0.0000000001deg);`

`text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);`

`font-smooth: always;`

Fonte (Em inglês): https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1846552

Comment: Cara eu tentei os 3 modos mas não ficou legal :(

Comment: O `font-smooth: always;` não funciou