# Pegar e exibir dados de um atributo do tipo class (associação entre classes)

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

Estou com um pequeno problema ao pegar um valor de um atributo do tipo `class`.

Classe Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa
    {
        public string Nome {get;set;}
        public int Idade {get;set;}

        public virtual void Add()
        {
            Nome = Console.ReadLine();
            Idade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }
```

Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente : Pessoa
    {
        public int Codigo {get;set;}
        public override void Add()
        {
           base.Add();
           Codigo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           Moto moto = new Moto();

           moto.AddMoto();
           moto.ExibirDados();

        }

}
```

Classe Moto

```
public class Moto
    {
          public string Cor {get;set;}
          public Pessoa Pessoa {get;set;}

          public void AddMoto()
          {
             Cor = Console.ReadLine();
          }
          public void ExibirDados()
          {
             Console.WriteLine("Titular: " + Pessoa); //Como fazer para mostrar o Nome da Pessoa Cadastrada?
             Console.WriteLine("Cor: " + Cor);
             Console.ReadKey();
          }
}
```

Não quero que no método `AddMoto` eu informe o titular da moto, apenas gostaria de uma maneira de pegar o valor que já se encontra salvo na variável `Nome` da classe `Pessoa`.

Comment: O propriedade pessoa da classe moto deve estar inicializada, você efetuou a inicialização dela? se sim basta utilizar `Pessoa.Nome`

Comment: Eu estou achando estas classes muitos esquisitas. E não tem uma explicação clara do que deseja, qual sua dificuldade. Então estou perdido em como te ajudar. A solução para o que está pedindo é até fácil, mas é algo completamente sem sentido. Porque uma `Moto` deve ter uma propriedade chamada `Pessoa`?  Não consigo imaginar uma explicação **plausível**. Então o problema parece estar aí. Se deixar de ter isto, começa fazer mais sentido. Ainda nem tanto. Misturar a lógica de entrada e saída de dados está torando tudo muito confuso. Tente explicar melhor o que realmente deseja.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade estava querendo fazer uma associação entre a classe Moto e Pessoa, onde o que gostaria de dizer é que uma pessoa pode ter uma moto. O objetivo de fazer isso é que quando exibir os dados da moto eu mostre quem é o dono da moto, mas sem a necessidade de durante o cadastro dos dados da moto eu ter que informar novamente quem é o titular pois já fiz isso no metódo `Add()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *design* está ruim, está misturando coisas. Não sei se entendi o que realmente deseja. Eu vou mudar para uma forma que está correta. Ainda não ficará tão correto porque as classes misturam coisas que deveriam estar em lugares separados. Entendo que seja só um exercício artificial, mas aprender errado com ele não vai ajudar.

A moto não deveria ter conhecimento sobre a pessoa que a detém. Se por acaso isto for necessário, então o *design* teria que ser mudado mais ainda. E teria que ter uma boa justificativa. Então fazendo que a moto manipule só dados da moto e o cliente só dados do cliente (que tem como parte integrante a pessoa), fica tudo certo.

Tem que entender o problema como ele realmente é. Querer criar uma situação artificial vai criar problemas mais cedo ou mais tarde. Claro que em um exercício não vai criar problemas, afinal ele não receberá manutenção, não terá requisitos alterados. Mas se fizer errado no exercício, aprenderá fazer errado depois.

No exemplo atual não existe motivo para ter um método virtual. Não é o caso de usar polimorfismo aqui.

Talvez fosse o caso de usar um construtor e não este método `Add()`. Principalmente se tirar a lógica de entrada e saída de dados que não deveria estar junto dos dados. Pra consertar as classes teria que refazer de forma tão radical que se tornaria outra coisa completamente diferente.

Também é muito estranho ter um método `Add()` em duas classes e um `AddMoto()` na outra, não faz sentido.

Tem outros problemas no código. Não vou tentar resolver tudo.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => new Cliente().Add();
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public virtual void Add() {
        Nome = ReadLine();
        Idade = int.Parse(ReadLine()); //não é assim que faz, só pra simplificar
    }
}

public class Cliente : Pessoa {
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public override void Add() {
        base.Add();
        Codigo = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        var moto = new Moto();
        moto.AddMoto();
        moto.ExibirDados();
        ExibirDados();
    }
    public void ExibirDados() => WriteLine("Titular: " + Nome);
}

public class Moto {
    public string Cor { get; set; }
    public void AddMoto() => Cor = ReadLine();
    public void ExibirDados() => WriteLine("Cor: " + Cor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/akeESj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8NPFzH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Association.cs).

Eu fico imaginando porque uma `Pessoa` e não um `Cliente` pode ser dono de uma `Moto` neste caso. Mesmo que isto seja possível, então `Cliente` é uma coisa e `Pessoa` é outra. Aí o `Cliente` pode ser até **composto por uma** `Pessoa`, mas não ser **a** `Pessoa`. Ou seja, o *design* estaria ainda mais errado. Considerando esta hipótese e considerando que os dados da pessoa e moto podem ser nulos (outro código vai cuidar disto) fiz um código melhor mas ainda com problemas. Algo assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var pessoa = new Pessoa();
        var moto = new Moto(pessoa);
        var cliente = new Cliente(moto);
        cliente.ExibirDados();
        cliente.Moto.ExibirDados();
        cliente.Pessoa.ExibirDados();
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public Pessoa() {
        Write("Nome: ");
        Nome = ReadLine();
        Write("Idade: ");
        Idade = int.Parse(ReadLine());  //não é assim que faz, só pra simplificar
    }
    public void ExibirDados() => WriteLine($"Nome: {Nome}");
}

public class Cliente {
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Moto Moto { get; set; }
    public Cliente() {
        Write("Código do cliente: ");
        Codigo = int.Parse(ReadLine());
    }
    public Cliente(Pessoa pessoa) : this() => Pessoa = pessoa;
    public Cliente(Moto moto) : this(moto.Pessoa) => Moto = moto;
    public void ExibirDados() => WriteLine($"Código: {Codigo}");
}

public class Moto {
    public string Cor { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Moto() {
        Write("Cor: ");
        Cor = ReadLine();
    }
    public Moto(Pessoa pessoa) : this() => Pessoa = pessoa;
    public void ExibirDados() => WriteLine($"Cor: {Cor}");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/w1rBMq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4tDtmV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Association2.cs).

Note que esta referência cruzada do `Cliente` que tem uma `Pessoa` X `Moto` que também tem uma `Pessoa` não me agrada. Mas aí vou ter que ir mais longe.

[Não sou fã do termo atributo aí, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9064/70).

Comment: Penso que se eu tivesse uma outra classe como por exemplo funcionário, poderia ter que indicar que aquela moto pertence ao funcionário que está sendo cadastrado juntamente com os dados da moto ou o cliente como foi o caso. Por isso uma Pessoa ser o detentor da moto. Mas de fato posso está errado na minha lógica. Bom mas a ideia é realmente somente um exercício básico o que queria aqui era compor duas classes e acessar os atributos de outra através de uso de propriedades do tipo de uma classe. Aceitamos sugestões de melhoria ou alternativa.

Comment: Bom e se tivesse uma classe Funcionário que herdasse também de Pessoa e tivesse também uma moto?

Comment: Eu acho que está ficando mais confuso ainda. Mostrei que a coisa é mais simples do que parece. O problema de exercícios artificiais é que os requisitos podem ser malucos, sem sentido. Aí os códigos para atender essas cosias serão malucos e sem sentido. Se você não tiver um problema bem definido, não terá um código usável. Entendo o que disse, mas não daria certo do jeito que estava fazendo. Agora  coloquei um exemplo que dá para adaptar para ter o funcionário, ainda que isto não faça sentido também. Funcionários não possuem motos. Se o cliente por acaso também é funcionário, é outro problema.

Comment: Note que o problema principal do código é consequência da definição errada do que é o problema. Também tem erros de estruturação do código em si, mas isso dá para relevar em exercício. O que não dá é fazer algo que não faça sentido e não vai resolver nenhum problema de fato. Dependendo do contexto do problema eu nem colocaria pessoa como dono da moto e sim o cliente. Ainda Tem várias melhorias que poderiam ser feitas aí, justamente para poder deixar ser mais extensível. Ainda que não do jeito que está pensando.

Comment: Obrigado, com sua ajuda consegui ajustar melhor meu código!