# Modelagem para cadastro de entidades abrangente

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Estou criando uma modelagem de cadastro da maneira mais abrangente possível.
As entidades são Pessoa, Pessoa Física, Pessoa Jurídica, Fornecedor e Cliente

Abaixo a entidade pessoa. Eu adiciono a pessoa os dados de contato e endereço para facilitar as consultas futuras.

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String ativo;
        private String apelido;
        private Endereco endereco;
        private String dataAtualizacao;
        private String foneResidencial;
        private String nome;
        private String foneCelular;
        private String foneProfissional;
        private String sexo;
        private String dataNascimento;
        private String dataCadastro;
        private String email;
}
```

Pessoa Tisica tá tranquila:

```
public class PessoaFisica {
    private String estadoEmissor;
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    private String RG;
    private String orgaoEmissor;
    private String dataAtualizacao;
    private String paisNascimento;
    private String CPF;
    private Profissao profissao;
    private String localNascimento;
    private String estadoNascimento;
    private EstadoCivil estadoCivil;
}
```

Pessoa Jurídica também tá tranquilo:

```
public class PessoaJuridica extends EntidadeAbstrata implements Serializable {
    private String nomeFantasia;
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    private String Razao;
    private String CNPJ;
}
```

O que está complicando pra mim é entender Cliente e Fornecedor.

Primeiro, quais atributos os diferenciariam dentro da base?

E o que eu acho mais difícil é: como meu `Cliente` ou `Fornecedor` poderia ser `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica` estando dentro da mesma tabela.

/********ATUALIZAÇÃO********/

Quando fiz a pergunta confesso que não tinha total certeza do que estava perguntado.
Vou explicar melhor minha ideia de 'girico'.

Estou tentando criar um modelo de cadastro abrangente não no sentido de ter uma modelagem pronta e que seja totalmente aplicada a qualquer negocio, mas no sentido de ter sempre um ponto de partida para qualquer sistema que eu venha a desenvolver.
Não nego que seja um desejo um tanto louco, masssss

Quando fiz a questão relacionada a Cliente e Fornecedor o fiz porque quanto se trata de Pessoa Fisica ou Juridica a coisa é mais clara, pelo menos pra mim.

Pessoa Fisica CPF, RG, Estado Civil etc
Pessoa Juridica  Razão, CNPJ, Inscrição Estadual etc

Quando perguntei sobre cliente/fornecedor achei que alguém com mais experiência identificaria atributos pra essas entidades mais facilmente.

Enfim, estou aberto a ideias e criticas. Bora ver no que dá

Valeu!

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua dúvida. Me esclareça melhor pra eu poder postar uma resposta. Qual a dificuldade de criar tabelas `Cliente` e `Fornecedor`? Nelas terão um campo que vincula à uma pessoa física ou jurídica **exclusivamente**, afinal uma pessoa só pode ser uma delas. Só achei meio estranho a inconsistência entre as duas pessoas, muito menos entendi o que é essa `EntidadeAbstrata`.

Comment: @bigown Seria o caso de um foreign key mais uma coluna de descriminação? Ou existe alguma outra solução.

Comment: Pode ser, mas não sei o que quer dizer com `descriminação`.

Comment: Uma coluna de Tipo exemplo: 'PF' ou 'PJ'

Comment: As informações que você passa estão muito truncadas, então qualquer afirmação que eu fizer pode estar certa ou errada. Deve ter uma coluna assim, mas depende. Tem outras coisas que precisam ser melhor definidas. Isto deve ir para um banco de dados o que exigirá uma chave primária. Indo ou não, seria interessante ter uma informação para dar unicidade ao dado. Como isto está sendo feito? Eu poderia ir mais longe e perguntar como estas classes serão usadas no sistema, pode ser que este modelo todo esteja errado, mas nem quero entrar nisso agora.

Comment: Na verdade é isso mesmo. Estou tentando criar a modelagem mais abrangente possivel. Por exemplo, nessa primeira versão ``Pessoa Jurifica`` referencia uma pessoa, mas ai eu me pergunto isso esta certo? Faz sentido?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que a forma de deixar o mais genérico possível é manter apenas **Pessoa Física** e **Pessoa Jurídica**, de forma que ambas são **Pessoas**, mas a melhor maneira de fazer isto é começar desenhando como você pode observar no Diagrama de Classes abaixo (Utilizando as suas classes como exemplo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta imagem é possível perceber que uma Pessoa pode ser qualquer tipo de pessoa, sendo que cada tipo de pessoa pode ser definido no **enum TipoPessoa**, desta forma se no futuro surgir a necessidade de adicionar um novo tipo, basta adicionar o novo tipo neste **enum**.

---

**COMO FICA NO CÓDIGO**

Isto pode ser escrito em java com 3 classes e 1 enumerador.

1. **TipoPessoa**

   ```
   public enum TipoPessoa {
           CLIENTE,
           FUNCIONARIO,
           FORNECEDOR, 
           CONTATO
   }
   ```
2. **Pessoa**

   ```
   public class Pessoa {
       private TipoPessoa tipoPessoa;
       private String nome;
       private String apelido;
       private Endereco endereco;
       private Date dataAtualizacao;
       private Date dataCadastro;
       private String email;
       private String fone;
   }
   ```
3. **PessoaFisica**

   ```
   public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa{
       private String rg;
       private String orgaoEmissor;
       private String cpf;
       //demais atributos
   }
   ```
4. **PessoaJuridica**

   ```
   public class PessoaJuridica  extends Pessoa{
       private String nomeFantasia;
       private String razaoSocial; //atualmente foi alterado para nomeEmpresarial
       private String cnpj;
       private PessoaFisica contato;
   }
   ```

---

**COMO UTILIZAR**

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]){

            PessoaJuridica cliente = new PessoaJuridica();
            cliente.setTipoPessoa(TipoPessoa.CLIENTE);
            cliente.setNome("Exemplo Cliente");
            cliente.setCnpj("123123123123");

            PessoaJuridica fornecedor = new PessoaJuridica();
            fornecedor.setTipoPessoa(TipoPessoa.FORNECEDOR);
            fornecedor.setNome("Exemplo Fornecedor");
            fornecedor.setCnpj("123123123333312");

            PessoaFisica clientePessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica();
            clientePessoaFisica.setTipoPessoa(TipoPessoa.CLIENTE);
            clientePessoaFisica.setNome("Exemplo Cliente Pessoa Fisica");
            clientePessoaFisica.setCpf("12312312333");

            PessoaFisica funcionario = new PessoaFisica();
            funcionario.setTipoPessoa(TipoPessoa.FUNCIONARIO);
            funcionario.setNome("Exemplo Funcionario");

            List<Pessoa> pessoas = new LinkedList<Pessoa>();
            pessoas.add(cliente);
            pessoas.add(funcionario);
            pessoas.add(fornecedor);
            pessoas.add(clientePessoaFisica);

            for(Pessoa p: pessoas){
                System.out.println(p.getNome() + " - " + p.getTipoPessoa());
            }
        }
    }
```

**SAIDA**

```
    Exemplo Cliente - CLIENTE
    Exemplo Funcionario - FUNCIONARIO
    Exemplo Fornecedor - FORNECEDOR
    Exemplo Cliente Pessoa Fisica - CLIENTE
```

Comment: Alguns pontos para se analisar: PessoaJuridica tem Nome ou Razão Social? Pessoa Juridica tem Apelido? PessoaJuridica tem Endereço?

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Nesta modelagem com certeza possui problemas de concordância, utilizar as informações da própria pergunta e organizei algumas, mas nos pontos citados, PessoaJurídica deve ter Nome Fantasia e Razão Social. Pessoa jurídica pode ter apelido mas isto depende do problema, e Pessoa Jurídica tem Endereço.

Comment: Muito interessante. E simplifica bastante o modelo.

Comment: Onde está os dados de cliente, fornecedor, etc? Como eles e relacionam com estes dados?

Comment: @Krismorte simplifica porque não faz o que você pede na pergunta. Não tem os dados específicos de cliente, fornecedor, etc. A entidade sequer pode ser cliente e fornecedor ao mesmo tempo, e se puder, mesmo que não tenha como colocar dados específicos. Este modelo é exatamente o que não se deve fazer. Você acaba tendo que cadastrar mais de uma vez a mesma entidade porque o modelo está errado. Não vou nem falar do fato de usar herança, porque não dá para dizer que está errado, mas tem suas desvantagens.

Comment: @bigown na verdade eu não estou trabalhando isso para um "projeto". Então não tenho de onde tirar os atributos e tal. Na verdade estou tentando criar uma modelagem bem abrangente no que diz respeito a cadastro. Desde o momento que iniciei não consegui identificar os atributos específicos de cliente e fornecedor. Sei de suas ações perante o sistema, mas na modelagem não consegui ver onde eles se diferem. Pode ser loucura da minha parte querer criar essa modelagem ou também falta de experiencia para identificar/prever atributos para esse modelo.

Comment: @Krismorte estou entendendo cada vez menos o que deseja. O seu problema é não saber quais os "campos" usar? Se for isso parece ser bem diferente do que perguntou. E se for, é difícil dizer, porque cada uma tem uma necessidade diferente. Aí entramos do problema de fazer coisas "virtuais". Se você não tem um requisito, qualquer coisa vale.

Comment: @bigow a pergunta pede uma forma de diferenciar Cliente e Fornecedor dentro da base de dados e um atributo para diferenciar Pessoa Fisica de Pessoa Jurídica dentro de uma mesma tabela. No modelo que passei isto pode ser solucionado, a menos que você pense em duas tabelas para PF e PJ, mas o modelo está mostrando uma herança que pode ficar dentro da mesma tabela. Outra colocação é que a Pessoa pode ser Cliente e Fornecedor ao mesmo tempo sim, basta criar um TipoPessea para esta situação ou alterar o relacionamento entre TipoPessoa e Pessoa de (* para 1) para (* para *).

Comment: @bigown respondendo a pergunta quanto aos dados de cliente, fornecedor, etc. Como o cadastro ficou generalizado se for informação que serve tanto para Pessoa Física quando Jurídica fica em "Pessoa", se for específico de Pessoa Física fica em "Pessoa Física" e se for específico de "Pessoa Jurídica" fica em "Pessoa Jurídica". Utilizei um modelo destes para fazer um sistema para contabilidade, onde o funcionário poderia ser cliente ou sócio de uma empresa cliente, ficou bem organizado e segue recomendações de Engenharia do Software como Sommerville e Wazlavick.

Comment: @ElyelRubensdaRosa e se tiver 20 tipos de relacionamento diferentes, você cria 400 enumerações? E se a informação só serve para quem é cliente? Fica onde? E se só serve para quem for fornecedor, fica onde? Você tem uma referência  dessas recomendações que falou?

Answer (score 2):

Várias formas são possíveis de acordo com a necessidade que não está clara. Poderia ser algo assim:

```
public class Cliente {
    private String CNPJ;
    private String CPF;
    private String Comprador; //só exemplos
    private DateTime UltimaVenda;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Model.java).

Os primeiros campos devem ser usados exclusivamente, assim é possível verificar qual está em uso analisando se o outro está nulo. Se achar que isto não é ideal, que precisa de algo mais concreto para validar e evitar mudanças acidentais, pode-se criar um campo que informa se a pessoa é física ou jurídica.

Obviamente que isto é uma simplificação da classe, seria interessante ter construtores e métodos que auxiliassem o bom uso dela. A não ser que seja puro DTO ou algo parecido, o que aí tem que seguir o que o banco de dados estabelecer.

Nem vou mostrar o fornecedor, é a mesma coisa, não importa qual é o **tipo de relação**.

Faz sentido, mas não garanto que atingirá todos os objetivos necessários. Parece estar tudo certo. Talvez poderia ser melhor.

O vínculo com `Pessoa` ser por uma referência para o objeto, não me agrada tanto. Faz sentido, mas pode limitar alguns cenários. Em banco de dados ou outra forma de persistência isto não funciona.

Eu gostei que não usou herança, acho que a composição ou o relacionamento é melhor neste caso. Outras pessoas teriam feito "OOP". Traria algumas vantagens, mas traria desvantagens também. Não existe modelo perfeito, tem que escolher com quais problemas quer lidar.

Algumas pessoas prefeririam vincular os objetos ao contrário. Ou seja, a `Pessoa` teria uma informação de vínculo com a `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica`. E cada uma dessas duas teriam campos para vincular com o tipo de relação que se tem com a entidade sendo cadastrada ali no objeto, ou seja, teria um campo para vincular com `Cliente`, outra com `Fornecedor`, e outras conforme for surgindo a necessidade. Isto permitiria circular com a `Pessoa` pela aplicação e acessar todas informações de uma pessoa específica. Obviamente exigiria mudança nas classes sempre que adicionar um tipo de relação novo (na verdade é possível ter uma classe auxiliar para lidar com isto sem obrigar mudanças na classe já existente).

No modelo atual o oposto também é válido, ainda que mais raro, afinal indo de baixo pra cima uma mudança nos tipos de pessoa é que forçaria mudanças em `Cliente`, `Fornecedor`, etc. Um dia pode surgir uma `PessoaEstrangeira`, o que forçaria a adição de um campo na classe aí em cima.

É possível ter uma padronização da informação de vínculo e ter apenas um campo de vínculo (no exemplo eu usei `CNPJ` E `CPF`), resolvendo a questão citada no parágrafo anterior e no anterior a este quando fala da adição de tipos de relação. Mas se feito isto, passaria ser obrigatório ter um campo dizendo qual o tipo da pessoa.

Eu acho que para dar flexibilidade o ideal é ter vínculos dos dois lados, ou seja, se você tiver `Pessoa`, você acessa os dados da `PessoaFisica` e de `Cliente` (só para ficar em um exemplo) daquela pessoa. Se tiver um objeto `Cliente`, consegue os dados de `PessoaFisica` e `Pessoa` geral relacionado a ele.

Alguma perguntas que podem interessar:

- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)
- [Banco de dados deve seguir o padrão OO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83702/101)
- [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)
- [Como funciona a herança de construtor em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45699/101)
- [Pegar e exibir dados de um atributo do tipo class (associação entre classes)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109591/101)

E [minha resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81628/101).

Se eu lembrar de outros detalhes, eu coloco depois.