# Modelagem de lançamentos usando clientes e fornecedores

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

#### Contextualização:

Inicialmente estou desenvolvendo um módulo de lançamento (contas a pagar e receber). Todo lançamento deve está relacionado a um fornecedor ou a um cliente.

Como desejo modelar detalhadamente tanto o cliente quanto o fornecedor, criarei uma tabela chamada "Cliente" e outra "Fornecedor".

#### Possíveis formas que encontrei para modelar o caso

1. Criar na tabela "Lancamento" uma coluna chamada "Interface", que receberá valores de um ENUM {"Cliente", "Fornecedor"}. Algo como 0 (cliente) ou 1 (fornecedor).
2. Criar duas colunas ("Cliente" e "Fornecedor") na tabela "Lancamento".

#### O problema

Identifiquei os seguintes problemas de acordo com as formas que encontrei para modelar:

- Caso 1: Em uma mesma coluna da tabela "Lancamento" vão ter dados de duas tabelas diferentes ("Fornecedor" e "Cliente").
- Caso 2: Vão existir duas colunas ("Fornecedor" e "Cliente") na tabela "Lancamento" e que, necessariamente, as duas nunca poderão estar preenchidas para uma mesma linha - Na aplicação, um lançamento é referente a um cliente ou a um fornecedor, nunca aos dois.

No caso 1, pensei em usar UNION, sendo um select na tabela "Cliente" e outro select na tabela "Fornecedor".

No caso 2, terei duas colunas com muitas dados vazios. Outra coisa é que toda vez que eu precisar alterar o tipo da interface (cliente ou fornecedor) de um lançamento, vou ter que fazer um UPDATE para remover o dado de uma coluna e preencher a outra. Por exemplo, alguém fez um lançamento incorreto no qual informou cliente ao invés de fornecedor.

#### Há alguma maneira mais simples de fazer isso?

Segue exemplo da tela do sistema.

[image: Tela de lançamento - A receber]

Modelagem que fiz até o momento
[image: Modelagem]

Comment: Tem mil maneiras. A que eu uso é simplesmente um campo que serve como se fossem "tags" (ou set, no lugar de enum). Como implementar, depende. Se for um campo numérico, você pode ter potências de 2 (1 cliente, 2 fornecedor, 4 prestador de serviço, 8 órgão público, etc). Assim, você não fica limitado a ser só uma coisa ou só outra coisa, e amanhã ou depois pode ter um tipo de valor 16, com novo significado, sem invalidar os dados já existentes. Se você é um escritório de contabilidade, compra papel do Zé da Esquina Ltda, e faz a contabilidade dele, ele é fornecedor e cliente, ou seja, tipo = 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenho que dizer quer [ter coluna vazia não é o fim do mundo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101). Mas eu não iria por esse caminho. Ele tem alguns problemas e um deles é que complica a extensibilidade, conforme o Bacco disse nos comentários, mas ela pode não te afetar. A lógica da aplicação vai ter que lidar com isso. Ainda que dependendo de como vai fazer isso, sempre será necessário. Conceitualmente não é o mais correto.

Entenda que [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) deve trabalhar a seu favor, nunca contra.

## Melhor opção entre as apresentadas

Então se vai fazer assim e ficar entre essas duas opções, o caso 1 parece mais adequado. E não vejo grandes problemas no que está fazendo. Não imagino como possa ser mais simples, se optar por seguir a linha atualmente adotada.

Eu não imaginava como poderia ser mais complicado, mas descobri aqui que é possível complicar bem mais que sua solução.

Obviamente precisa indicar em algum lugar qual é aquela informação. Como fazer isso depende de alguns parâmetros não informados.

Isso pode dar algum problema? Pode dependendo do que possa precisar. Aí não teria como responder sem entender todo o caso em detalhes. Mas o maior problema é não saber se um dia isso pode se tornar um problema.

Isso essencialmente responde a questão.

## Conceito errado

Eu acho possível ser um problema porque essa forma é conceitualmente errada. Eu sei que quase todo mundo faz assim e depois ficam arrumando "soluções criativas" (o termo é pejorativo mesmo) para resolver os problemas.

Nada que faça pode garantir que não terá dificuldades futuras. Mas quando o conceito está errado é mais fácil se ver em dificuldades no futuro.

O conceito correto não determina que tem relações com clientes e fornecedores. As relações são com entidades que por acaso em determinado momento se comportam como um cliente ou como um fornecedor perante uma operação no seu sistema.

Se fizer assim pode ser mais simples, ou pelo menos mais simples de lidar da forma correta como as coisas são de verdade no mundo real. E aí o dilema da pergunta some. Convenhamos que normalmente não importa qual o papel da entidade está tendo nesse lançamento. Interessa que ela tem algo para receber ou pagar.

Mas se tiver um motivo poderia colocar o papel exercido. Tem que levantar os requisitos corretamente. Nunca fará um sistema correto se os requisitos estiverem errados ou incompletos. Na minha experiência quase sempre eles estão errados.

Claro que provavelmente terá que reformular todo o seu sistema e talvez nem saiba como fazer corretamente. Se achar que não deve fazer essa mudança, ok, aí vai do jeito que está pretendendo e torça para não aparecer novas dificuldades.

## Finalizando

Uma coisa que eu vou comentar é que não gosto do termo "interface". É apenas gosto, mas acho algo que os usuários não entendem intuitivamente.

Se deseja entender mais sobre essa questão das entidades e papeis que elas exercem eu já dei [várias respostas sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123499/101). E lá talvez veja que o problema é até mais complicado do que está imaginando.

- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)
- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)

Não gosto muito de colocar isso em resposta, mas tem gente que acha essa modelagem polêmica porque não é a mais comum e muita gente não quer inovar. Cada um faz como achar melhor, eu faço assim porque fui desenvolvedor de um ERP líder de mercado usado em milhares de empresas brasileiras e estrangeiras de todos portes e ramos de atividade. Eu sei a dor de cabeça que é conceituar errado. Todos os dias tínhamos que inventar gambiarras porque o modelo não foi conceituado certo desde o início.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Minha sugestão é que no lugar de você criar uma tabela Cliente e outra Fornecedor para associá-las diretamente ao Lançamento, você crie uma tabela que represente uma abstração dos mesmos associada ao Lançamento. Assim só haveria uma chave para Lançamento que apontaria para a tabela "IndividuoLancamento". Para as informações específicas do Cliente ou do Fornecedor, você criaria uma coluna em cada uma dessas tabelas apontando para "IndividuoLancamento" (id_individuo_lancamento). Para manter uma relação nxn (vários clientes para vários lançamento) você criaria uma tabela intermediária de mapeamento entre cliente, fornecedor e indivíduo lançamento. Dessa forma, você mantém os dados do teu banco normalizados e tem como identificar se o indivíduo lançamento é um Cliente ou Fornecedor. Ficaria algo como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De curiosidade, só pra eu entender melhor: qual seria a vantagem da tabela `IndividuoLancamento` separada, em vez de ter um campo `IdIndividuo` `tipoIndividuo` direto em `Lancamento`, economizando um join? (tenho a impressão que talvez eu não tenha enxergado algum detalhe).

Comment: Mas o id_individuo seria polimórfico, como ele iria saber se era um cliente ou fornecedor? A vantagem da tabela separada é deixar isso mais claro.

Comment: `tipoIndividuo` seria para isso, identificar. Claro que foi só um exemplo, podia ser um bool como `isClient`, qq coisa assim. É que de qq forma `Individuolancamento` ia ser polimórfico também no seu exemplo. Mas era só pra entender a idéia geral mesmo, vou pensar melhor no que vc comentou.

Comment: Entendo, mas a consulta seria mais complexa e precisaria de case para saber qual join fazer. Para questões de normalização ficaria melhor separar isso sem manter colunas polimórficas.

Comment: Acho que tou começando a entender. No caso atual, o `ClienteFornecedorLancamento` funcionaria sem o CASE para relacionar com `Cliente` ou `Fornecedor` então?

Comment: Isso, porque seria feito um left join para trazer ou cliente ou fornecedor.

Comment: Oi Giuliana. Obrigado pela resposta, mas não entendi muito bem o motivo da tabela "ClienteFornecedorLancamento". Sua resposta foi parecida com meu Caso 1.

Comment: Só precisa dessa tabela para simular o relacionamento nxn de clientefornecedor e lançamento. Porque você terá situações em que, por exemplo, o mesmo cliente fará mais de um lançamento. Para isso, você iria precisar de uma tabela que guarde a relação entre o cliente e seus diversos lançamentos. A diferença é que a solução que estou propondo mantém as tabelas normalizadas.