# Normalização de tabela para 2a Forma Normal

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

> Uma relação encontra-se na 2FN se e somente se estiver na 1FN e não
>   contém dependências parciais.

A partir desta definição estou normalizando um BD para 2FN. Esse BD possui 2 tabelas, qual ilustra a figura com seus respectivos atributos:

[image: Estado atual das tabelas]

A **chave candidata `cpf` da tabela `cliente`**, está causando dependência parcial nesse formato, certo? Pois apenas `id` já o referência.

Reorganizando a tabela `cliente` de acordo com a 2FN acabei por defini-la assim, a ideia central do meu pensamento de normalização está correta?

Há alguma outra forma melhor para que eu possa normalizá-la?

[image: Novo modelo]

Comment: "Gostaria de"... ?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/64969

Comment: Opa, acabei por editar o final. Então estou querendo saber se o cpf deixa a a tabela desrespeitando a transitividade, pois apesar de ver desta forma, alguns de meus amigos de equipe tem opinião contrária a minha. A partir disso gostaria de entender então se eu estou errado e quem está errado e o porque. Obrigado pelo compartilhamento do link, ajuda como um material adicional de estudos, mas preciso da ajuda nesse caso em específico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suas tabelas `Cliente` e `Agência` estão na primeira forma normal porque nenhum campo é multivalorado, então vamos focar na segunda forma normal.

Há duas chaves candidatas na tabela `Cliente`: `id` e `cpf`. Claramente a partir do `id`, podemos obter qualquer outro campo e a partir do `cpf` também. E também não podemos utilizar apenas uma parte do `id` ou do `cpf` para esse fim.

Já na tabela `Agencia`, a única chave candidata é o `id` e os demais campos são definidos com base no `id` e não apenas em parte do `id`.

Entretanto, os campos `estado` são determinados pelos campos `cidade` que por sua vez são determinados pelo campos `rua` na tabela `Cliente` e `cep` na tabela `Agencia`. Ou seja, os campos `cidade` e `estado` são violações da segunda forma normal porque eles não depende da chave primária, e sim de algum outro campo. A sua tentativa de normalizar não corrige esse problema completamente, mas já é um passo em alguma direção.

A solução seria:

- Crie uma tabela `Estado` com os campos `codigo` e `nome`.

  O `codigo` é a chave primária, enquanto que o `nome` é uma outra chave candidata porque não podemos ter dois estados com o mesmo nome.
- Crie uma tabela `Cidade` com os campos `codigo_estado`, `codigo_cidade` e `nome`.

  O `codigo_cidade` é a chave primária, o `codigo_estado` é a chave estrangeira para a tabela `Estado`.

  Os campos `codigo_estado` e `nome` também são uma chave candidata porque não podem haver duas cidades com o mesmo nome no mesmo estado.

  O campo `nome` sozinho não é chave candidata porque podem haver cidades com o mesmo nome em estados diferentes (tal como Cascavel, nome de uma cidade no Paraná e uma no Ceará).
- Crie uma tabela `Logradouro` com os campos `cep`, `codigo_cidade`, `bairro` e `nome`.

  `cep` é a chave primária.

  `codigo_cidade` é a chave estrangeira para a tabela `Cidade`.

  Seria de se imaginar que `codigo_cidade` e `nome` juntos fossem uma chave candidata, e em quase todas as cidades isso seria verdade, mas nem sempre é. Em São Paulo, por exemplo, existem três ruas diferentes chamadas de "Rua Piracicaba". Assim sendo, a chave candidata é `codigo_cidade`, `nome` e `bairro`.
- Crie uma tabela `Endereco` com os campos `id`, `cep`, `numero_logradouro` e `complemento`.

  `id` é a chave primária.

  `cep` é a chave estrangeira para a tabela `Logradouro`.

  Curiosamente, o número do logradouro nem sempre é numérico. Por exemplo: "*Rua João da Silva, **148-B**, casa dos fundos*".
- Nas tabelas `Agencia` e `Cliente`, coloque uma chave estrangeira para `Endereco` e retire os demais campos referentes a endereços.

Esse modelo ainda não está perfeito, pois uma mesma rua pode ter diferentes CEPs e talvez fosse o caso de ter uma tabela de bairros e também uma tabela de tipos de logradouros (avenida, rua, praça, alameda, travessa, rodovia, quadra, etc.). Entretanto, para o seu propósito, isso deve ser o suficiente.

Comment: Isso não geraria uma excessiva quantidade de tabelas? Como não estou no mercado ainda, esse seria um procedimento correto para se normalizar e implementar?

Comment: @GustavodosSantosSorati O processo de normalização sempre gera uma inflação no número de tabelas. E se o seu exercício pede para normalizar isso, você vai ter que realizar o processo quantas vezes forem necessárias até eliminar as dependências funcionais, e em cada etapa vai ter ao menos uma tabela a mais. Assim sendo, pode se acostumar com isso, ver um grande número de tabelas novas surgir a partir da normalização é comum.

Answer (score 4):

Normalização existe essencialmente para resolver redundâncias. Vê alguma redundância aí?

## Endereço

Nenhuma mostrada. É possível o cliente ter mais de um endereço? É possível mais de um cliente ter o mesmo endereço? Se puder, **talvez** faça sentido aplicar a normalização neste caso. Com apenas um endereço não faz sentido fazer esta separação. Não se aplica nem a segunda, nem nenhuma forma normal.

Note que no segundo exemplo criou uma tabela chamada `Cliente Endereço`. Porque está colocando o endereço de uma agência nele? Não faz sentido.

Vamos supor que na verdade ela é uma tabela de endereços em geral. Aí até caberia colocar o endereço ali. Mas para que?

Nada impede de ter uma tabela só para endereços, mas se não há repetição do dado não está fazendo isto por normalização. Isto faz sentido se as entidades puderem ter mais de um endereço ou mais de uma delas ter o mesmo endereço.

Não entrei na normalização da tabela de endereço porque não parece ser o foco da pergunta e na forma apresentada pode até estar normalizada, não tem dados indicando o que estão as colunas, nem mesmo os tipos, poderia muito bem ser `ids` dos dados normalizados. Também pode ser que não se queira normalizar isto.

## Agência

Foi criada uma tabela para separar a agência que ele pertence. Novamente, tem mais de uma agência que o cliente pode ter? É a mesma questão do endereço. Qua ganho acho que teve fazendo isto? Que problema acha que resolveu? Normalização precisa resolver problemas, não causar novos. Não vi vantagem.

## Melhor modelo

Mesmo esses casos podem ser questionados em bancos de dados modernos. Não custa tão caro assim manter espaço para mais de um endereço na própria entidade. Nem sempre é problema ter uma muito eventual repetição de cadastro do endereço quando duas entidades estão no mesmo endereço. É uma questão de pragmatismo.

Se puder ter esses casos, estritamente falando, deveria normalizar, mas um desenvolvedor experiente vai analisar o quanto vale o esforço porque complica o modelo dificultando todo o código e performance. Então tem que pensar se compensa, se é tão necessário assim.

Por outro lado todo o modelo pode estar errado. Essa ideia de separar entidades em cliente, fornecedor, banco, etc. é errada por natureza. Pelo menos na forma apresentada.

Entidades são pessoas físicas e jurídicas (separadas). Cliente, fornecedor, banco, transportadora, vendedor, funcionário, etc. são papeis que essas pessoas exercem nessa organização. Nestas tabelas só deveriam ter dados sobre os papéis. Os dados da pessoa em si deveriam estar nas tabelas de pessoas física e jurídica. Isto é o mais correto, mas novamente é possível pragmaticamente fazer de outra forma se fizer sentido. Mas precisa escolher outra forma porque é o melhor e não porque é a única forma que conhece. Nem todos os casos fazem sentido separar assim, mas em geral é o mais correto.

Eu poderia apontar outros possíveis erros nesse modelo. Mas seria especulação porque só é certo ou errado sabendo todos os requisitos. Os erros que eu vejo seriam de acordo com minha experiência, não com o caso real, estão poderia estar certo ou não.

## [Normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101)

Para saber como normalizar precisa saber dos objetivos. Ser o mais correto formalmente, ser o mais rápido de desenvolver, ser o mais fácil de dar manutenção, ser o mais performático, ser o que o professor ensinou ou o chefe mandou mesmo que não seja o melhor, ou o que for. Não dá para normalizar cegamente. Até onde normalizar e onde parar é algo que aprenderá com o tempo.

- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)
- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)
- [Modelagem de lançamentos usando clientes e fornecedores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mineiro, então irei refazer. Eu tinha resolvido normalizar dessa forma pois não consigo enxergar o CPF de cliente não criando dependência parcial com numAgencia, você não enxerga desta forma? Eu até compreendi todo o resto que me explicou, mas essa relação, (id, numAgencia > cpf) ainda está complicada, sendo que com  (id > CPF), poderia me ajudar entender isso, obrigado pelos link

Comment: Eu não consigo enxergar uma relação entre essas duas coisas. CPF é do cliente, agência nada tem a ver com isso.

Answer (score 2):

#### Baseado nos exemplos de conversão do livro, segue abaixo um exemplo de 1FN para 2FN e 2FN para 3FN.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Baseado no desenho do livro, Fiz um desenho para tentar ajudar na sua pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como a sua pergunta se limitou a conversão apenas até a 2FN , eu não fiz a conversão da 2FN para 3FN como mostra o exemplo do livro.

> Considere as chaves primárias as palavras com sublinhado total , EX: (`CPF`) e as chaves estrangeira como (`_CEP`) com o underline antes da palavra.

Acrescentei alguns atributos não chave na tabela de relacionamento CLIENTE_AGENCIA somente para ficar mais coerente a ilustração, já que você não citou nenhum atributo relevante para compor essa tabela.

fonte: Sistemas de Banco de dados 6ª edição, autores: Elmasri, Ramez Navathe, Shamkant B. Ano: 2011