# Qual a vantagem de um relacionamento 1:1?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, relacionamento

Eu tenho um banco de dados (MySQL), e em uma tabela estou tendo cerca de 80 colunas. Estou pensando em separar essa informações em demais tabelas, e manter um relacionamento 1:1. Porem isso pode impactar um pouco no tempo de desenvolvimento, criar mais objetos, etc.

Qual a vantagem de utilizar diversas tabelas com relacionamento 1:1, em vez de utilizar tudo na mesma tabela?

Comment: Você não tem anomalias com update/delete ou perda de informção, uma tabela do banco de dados também não é um planilha de excel xD. Leitura super recomendada => [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/91)

Comment: Por exemplo se na tabela `funcionario` tiver um coluna com a descrição do `cargo` digamos que quando o último estagiário for promovido ou demito (delete nesse caso) nenhum outro funcionário podera ter esse cargo pq ele não existe mais. Agora se no lugar da descrição do cargo tivesse o id do cargo esse evento não causaria nenhuma perda de informação.

Comment: Entendi, e eu posso ter algum ganho com performance, com isso? Sendo que em 95% dos casos onde realizo query nessa tabela, não vou trazer todos os dados, mas somente dados específicos.

Comment: Sim e não. **Sim** pq se quebrar em varias tabelas vai eliminar valores duplicados o que resulta em menos linhas em uma tabela ou se precisa de algo especifico só pega o necessário. **Não** a performace geralmente diminu pq vai precisar de alguns joins para trazer toda a informação necessária pela consulta já que agora elas estão separadas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No comentário acho que está falando do relacionamento N:1. Muitas pessoas confundem com 1:1. A não ser que o texto esteja só confuso por causa do curto espaço máximo imposto.

A N:1 é por causa da [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101), ali o exemplo eventualmente se torna 1:1, mas por circunstância, não por obrigatoriedade, não é formalmente 1:1. Neste caso, isolando o dado você pode fazer manutenção nele e isso se reflete em todos os lugares que ele foi usado. Se estiver na própria tabela, ele se torna repetitivo e uma manutenção nele tem que descobrir em todos os lugares que foi usado e mudar tudo (tipo "NoSQL"). E ainda corre o risco de ele ser entrado errado de forma não padronizada e nem conseguir identificar onde ele foi usado. A normalização cria uma forma canônica para lidar com isso. Muitas pessoas não percebem que isso é [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), provavelmente o conceito que se a pessoa dominar totalmente nem precisa aprender tão bem outros.

Muitas vezes olhamos o 1:(0,1) como 1:1. O 1:1 de verdade obriga os dois lados terem 1, em alguns casos pode ser que um lado obrigatoriamente tem um, mas o outro pode ter zero.

O 1:1 geralmente usa-se por alguns motivos:

- O domínio (objeto) é totalmente diferente, e dos dois lados só pode ter um.

  Um exemplo que eu dou muito é a [pessoa que tem dados do seu papel como cliente, fornecedor, funcionário, etc.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101) A pessoa só pode ter um dado de cada um desses papéis (cada papel tem sua tabela) e cada cadastro do papel só pode pertencer a uma pessoa. Isto é claramente 1:1, ou 1:(0,1) já que na maioria das vezes uma pessoa pode não ter um papel específico. Muita gente não enxerga assim porque eles duplicam entidades no banco de dados ou fazem [tabelas](http://wiki.c2.com/?GodTable)/[classes "deuses"](http://wiki.c2.com/?GodClass). A maioria dos modelos por aí são cópias do que já existia, a pessoa não pensa nele, e faz errado.

  Outros exemplos 1:1 ou 1:(0,1):

  Uma pessoa pega um celular da empresa. Uma pessoa só pode pegar um celular de cada vez (regra da empresa) e esse celular só está com uma pessoa (ela pode ter 0 celulares). Mas se quiser manter históricos dos celulares já pegos, o modelo não funciona mais.

  Só existe um chefe no departamento e chefe só gerencia um departamento (alguma regra pode deixar ser diferente, mas vamos tratar que sempre é assim nessa empresa, mas se alguma regra mudar, já era).

  Uma pessoa só tem um cônjuge atual (tem país que não é assim), mas pode ter zero.

  Um cliente só pode reservar um quarto no hotel e o quarto só pode estar reservado para um cliente (considerando que não se faz *overbooking*).

  [Wikipedia tem mais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)) (o exemplo da capital tem exceção, embora dê para contorná-la e deixar 1:1). Ou seja, todos funcionam se a regra for muito rígida.
- Muitos dados são opcionais, em tese pode-se ir até a sexta forma normal para resolver isso. Muitas vezes quando isto corre é porque o domínio talvez fosse diferente e a pessoa não percebeu.

  Se as pessoas soubessem usar o modelo relacional direito e os SGDBRs tivessem colocado alguns recursos antes, talvez não existisse o [NoRel (que as pessoas chamam de NoSQL)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101).
- Partes secundárias dos dados de uma tabela/objeto raramente são acessadas junto com a parte principal. Então é uma otimização manter separado e não ter que tocar (ler ou escrever) nessas partes (ajuda o cache e reduz a área de travamento automático em concorrência e pode ter menos contatos com o armazenamento de massa permanente, que é lento, em importações longas). Essa otimização precisa ser muito bem pensada porque muitas vezes pode ser pior do que espera. Também possa ajudar se a pessoa abusa do `SELECT *`, mas é a solução para um problema que nem deveria existir.

  O que é mais rápido depende de uma série de fatores que muitas vezes nem conseguimos antecipar antes do sistema ser usado efetivamente. E muitas vezes otimizamos coisas que não precisavam ou que ficam pior do que esperávamos. Quase sempre fazer isso antes de saber que precisa é otimização prematura.

  Geralmente as pessoas ignoram a modelagem lógica. As pessoas sempre pensam na modelagem física. É possível fazer a modelagem lógica do jeito mais organizado e a física do jeito mais otimizado.

  Muitas pessoas usam pensando nisso, mas no fundo os dados eram de um domínio diferente e o motivo real que a pessoa usou, sem perceber, é o anterior.
- Alguns casos tem tantas colunas que fica quase não gerenciável assim. Divide-se, mas de novo, provavelmente estão criando uma modelagem errada e misturando dados de objetos que deveriam ser diferentes.
- Cada aplicação/operação deve ter privilégios para acessar uma parte, mas não outra e para dar esses privilégios geralmente tem que separar as tabelas (deficiência do banco de dados). Provavelmente era outro domínio de qualquer forma.
- Pode demorar muito para adicionar uma coluna nova na tabela e poderia bloquear as aplicações de usar a tabela por muito tempo (deficiência do DB), aí é melhor criar uma tabela nova associando. É gambiarra, claro.
- Pode ser assim por questões de replicação ou alguma estratégia específica, uma questão mais técnica.
- O modelo do ORM ou outra ferramenta que a pessoa usa ou por alguma questão relacionada ao legado exige algo assim.
- Pode estar facilitando uma estratégia de cache.
- A pessoa não tem noção do que está fazendo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No exemplo `1:1`, eu particularmente percebi como sendo `1:[0,1]`. Afinal, uma `Pessoa` pode simplesmente existir, sem ainda estar atrelada a ser `Cliente` ou `Funcionario`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tens razão, vou melhorar isso.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu só percebi como caso `1:1` isso: _Partes secundárias dos dados de uma tabela/objeto_; mas mesmo nesses casos eu concordo muito com sua ressalva que provavelmente seja uma otimização prematura (faltam uns 4 itens para eu terminar de ler)

Comment: Quem vai determinar a regra do relacionamento é o domínio, espero que com a edição isto fique mais claro. Não existe regra fixa, por isso não dá para afirmar que é ou não é sem conhecer o caso específico. Eu idealizei alguns casos que teriam regras que fazer ser 1:1 ou 1:(0,1).

Comment: Ficou muito boa a edição

Answer (score 7):

> Qual a vantagem de utilizar diversas tabelas com relacionamento 1:1, em vez de utilizar tudo na mesma tabela?

Eu diria que as vantagem mais significantes seriam:

- *Segmentacão por domínio*
  Assuma um caso onde uma tabela possui os dados de Clientes, incluindo Telefones. Estes são dois domínios diferentes, e diferentes casos de uso podem ser aplicados se a tabela for particionada (dois Clientes com um mesmo Telefone, ou um Cliente com dois Telefones.)
- *Particionamento de domínios 1:[0..1] (Zero ou Um)*
  Uma tabela única pode conter baixa densidade de dados (vários registros com uma grande quantidade de campos com valor NULL ou equivalente). O particionamento neste caso ajudaria na performance em queries (já que o engine não teria que ignorar valores fora de escopo.)

Comment: Telefone**S** já é 1:N. Se for telefon**E**, aí não vejo sentido a não ser que tenha um monte de dados relacionados, mesmo assim, com ressalvas, e não vejo isto ocorrendo. Se está separado porque várias pessoas podem ter o mesmo telefone é N:1. O motivo é real, o exemplo não é 1:1

Comment: @Maniero na verdade eu quis expressar a presença de N Clientes e N Telefones *na mesma tabela*, não que a tabela possui, por exemplo, os campos `Telefone1` e `Telefone2`.

Comment: Acredito que o exemplo ficaria melhor, como: Eu tenho um cadastro de Imovel, e o Imovel, tem um Endereço. (um endereço só pode ser um imóvel, e um imóvel pertence a somente um endereço). Ou seja, 1:1.

Comment: @EricoSouza concordo, este é um exemplo válido. Ainda assim um Cliente pode possuir ou não um imóvel, ou possuir N imóveis. Segmentação por domínio permitiria a expressão destes casos de uso sem repetição (ou omissão).

Comment: @OnoSendai Na verdade não: `(dois Clientes com um mesmo Telefone, ou um Cliente com dois Telefones.)`, isto é 1:N, N:1 ou até N:M se pode ambos. Isto é a definição do que não é 1:1.

Comment: @OnoSendai, certo, mas falando do dominio Imóvel, e ImovelEndereço. É melhor dividir em 2 tabelas? Pensando que na maioria das vezes que utilizo os dados da tabela imóvel, não preciso dos dados da tabela ImovelEndereço.

Comment: @Maniero, esse meu pensamento acima, é válido?

Comment: @Maniero Sim, eu concordo. E este é o ponto: No caso de segmentação por domínio, a vantagem é que *agora é possível expressar relacionamentos 1:N sem repetição*. No modelo monolítico seria necessário ou repetir os dados do cliente + o novo telefone, ou criar um campo a mais.

Comment: @EricoSouza Logicamente falando um imóvel só pode possuir um endereço, a não ser que você considere *trailers*, por exemplo. No primeiro caso o endereço de um imóvel é parte do seu domínio, e eu não vejo necessidade de particionamento.

Comment: @EricoSouza sim, mas me parece que seja só como otimização. Pra mim o endereço do imóvel é o mesmo domínio do imóvel. Mas pode ter alguma regra que diga o contrário. Não vejo o imóvel existir sem o endereço e o endereço sem o imóvel e me parece o mesmo objeto. Precisaria justificar porque o endereço deve ser separado. Só consigo ver por causa de desempenho (o que duvido que seja necessário). Mas pode ter alguma que não sei que conceitualmente seja diferente mesmo. Conceitualmente pra mim é a mesma coisa e deve estar na mesma tabela.

Comment: @OnoSendai mas a questão é essa, o exemplo não fala de um caso que seja 1:1. O exemplo é correto e útil, mas ele não é 1:1.

Comment: @Maniero legal, agora você me fez pensar, e ter uma visão que eu ainda não tinha. Realmente, Se eu vou utilizar uma tabela SÓ para endereço de imóvel, não faria mto sentido deixar separada. Agora se a tabela endereço for utilizada para mais coisas, já faz mais sentido.

Comment: @EricoSouza é isso aí. Por isso que o modelo NoRel costuma ser furado na maioria dos problemas que resolvemos. NoRel prega objetos deuses e o mundo real não é assim. Cria-se pesadelos em muitos casos, pelo menos em negócios. Isso funciona qdo vc pode estabelecer regras. Sabe porque o Gmail não tem um monte de *feature* que outros clientes de e-mail tem? Poque elas não se encaixam no modelo do banco de dados deles. É, ferram a UX pra ter mais eficiência no banco de dados.A SE faz isso com esse site em alguns pontos.Falei disso em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252792/101 ,mas teve quem ñ gostou

Comment: @Maniero  Se eu preciso armazenar tanto o endereço do imóvel quanto endereço de moradia um usuario e endereço de trabalho de um usuario, como devo proceder?
Crio uma tabela endereço, e crio uma coluna endereco_id como chave estrangeira para a tabela endereco.id na tabela imovel?
E na tabela usuario crio duas colunas também como chave estrangeira para a tabela endereco.id: endereco_moradia_id e endereco_trabalho_id? Estaria errado fazer dessa forma?

Comment: Isso é um problemas diferente do que está respondido aqui.