# É uma má prática armazenar CPF e CNPJ em uma mesma coluna do banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, entity-framework, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software

Em um fluxo que permita o cadastro de pessoas físicas e pessoas jurídicas já vi as duas abordagens, mas não tenho certeza se é uma boa prática armazenar as duas informações em uma coluna `cpf_cnpj` e aí ter um campo de *flag* para informar o tipo do campo, ou até mesmo utilizar a quantidade de caracteres no campo me parece um tanto quanto forçado.

Será que como estou utilizando ORM (Entity Framework) poderia ser melhor prática ter uma derivação do tipo `User` para `PersonalUser` e `BusinessUser`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquise aqui mesmo no site que eu e outras pessoas acham sobre "boas práticas".

Boa prática é fazer o certo para o que precisa. E só você com seu caso concreto pode dizer o que é certo para aquele caso.

Eu separo sempre pessoa física de jurídica, porque claramente elas são entidades muito diferentes. Mas funciona manter junto, eu acho que dá mais trabalho e complica algumas coisas. Minha experiência é que ainda que dê um pouco de trabalho separar é mais correto conceitualmente e acaba simplificando algumas coisas. Se souber abstrair bem isso nem é tão difícil lidar com ambos.

E esse último ponto é importante porque não adianta você tomar uma decisão certa e todas as outras que virem a seguir, até em consequência dessa, forem erradas. E esse é só mais um motivo para a adoção de boa prática pode ser uma péssima prática, a pessoa acha que ela basta e tudo ficará ótimo.

É como as pessoas adotando a "boa prática" de microsserviços porque escala mais facilmente. Ela só não sabe que está adotando o problema mais difícil da computação na sua arquitetura e que ela provavelmente fará tudo errado e será muito pior.

Aí entramos naquela coisa: "a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você conhece", ou dito de outra forma:

> A melhor prática é aquela que você conseguirá fazer certo

Eu só acho estranho um usuário pode ser jurídico. Não me lembro de ter visto isso em algum lugar. Vi entidades de relacionamento serem empresas, mas não usuários. Parece, mas não posso afirmar que há uma confusão de conceitos aí. Novamente, você é quem sabe dos seus requisitos.

O que eu não faço é separar atividades dessas entidades como clientes, fornecedores, etc.

Já dei algumas respostas sobre isso:

- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Como se modela um papel em orientação a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101)
- [Modelagem de lançamentos usando clientes e fornecedores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101)
- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela presteza na resposta. Na realidade como se trata de uma aplicação fintech, teremos a possibilidade um usuário PF poder se cadastrar a fim de realizar operações bancárias, e da mesma maneira no futuro a ideia é contemplar suporte a contas para empresas e pessoas jurídicas. Estou tentando estruturar um backend para essa aplicação. Vou ler as suas respostas com certeza.

Comment: Ter conta PF e PJ é diferente de ter usuário, inclusive é comum uma empresa querer ter vários usuários, por isso eu falei que eu acho que o conceito pode estar errado.

Comment: Sim, ainda vou dar mais uma analisada com a parte de negócios para entender a questão mais a fundo. Obrigado pelo heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não gosto muito da ideia de juntar tudo e usar flags ou tamanho de strings para diferenciar PF de PJ. Amanha o governo pode criar um terceiro (tipo ONG) que não é nem fisico nem juridico. E ai sua flag fica sem sentido. Definir pelo tamanho tambem nao acho uma boa, pois os numeros podem crescer. Ja vi lugares que reservam 15 digitos para PJ, 12 para PF, 9 para telefones fixos... e por ai vai...

Eu prefiro a abordagem que vi numa empresa em que trabalhei: Uma tabela para pessoa contendo dados comuns a ambos os tipos, uma tabela para PF e uma tabela para PJ. A tabela PJ armazenava somente a base do CNPJ e existia uma outra tabela que armazenava as filiais, a parte que vem depois da '/'. Porque uma coisa que muitos nao lembram são as filiais de um CNPJ.

Confuso né? Mas pra facilitar, foi criada uma view que juntava tudo, PF, PJ e suas filiais.

Alguns torcem o rabo para views, por questões de performance, etc.. So what? As maquinas estão cada vez mais rápidas, não vejo preocupação pra isso.

Comment: Já existe um terceiro que é a pessoa estrangeira  jurídica com regras diferentes em cada país. Não é necessário em todo tipo de cadastro mas existe isso, em geral para comércio exterior. E podem existir outras especificidades, por isso tende a ser uma boa estratégia separar, mas não acho que essa é a maior razão, ainda que ela seja válida também. E o problema nem é o tipo é todo o resto que pode mudar. Realmente o tamanho pode ser problemático, mas dá para resolver. A solução de ter uma tabela para pessoa e outras para PF e PJ é conceitualmente correta, porém não é performática, pode ir bem...

Comment: ... em alguns cenários, mas um dia a situação muda e isso passa ser um problema. Não acho uma tabela para filiais uma boa ideia, mas pode ser que eu não saiba de algo que sabe. É possível na mesma tabela diferenciar isso de forma mais adequada. A ideia da *view* bem implementada pode ser útil em alguns cenários, mas pode ser um indicador de problema. Eu ia positivar mas o fato de dizer que performance não importa é um erro.

Comment: Se as máquinas estivem tão rápidas que isso não é mais problemas as pessoas não recorriam mais a microsserviços porque elas deixaram o software tão lento que nenhuma máquina dá conta mais mesmo em volumes não tão grandes assim. Por isso tem site pequeno ou coisa interna que precisa de microsserviço e este site que é um dos 30 mais acessados do Brasil não precisa e poderia rodar em uma máquina. No resto a resposta é boa, por oferecer alternativas que faz algum sentido.

Comment: Não interprete errado. Alguns acham que views tem performance ruim, mas isso nao significa que realmente terá performance ruim. Esta solução roda em uma das maiores seguradoras do pais (onde trabalho atualmente) e nao vejo nada de performance ruim. Pelo contrario, é totalmente escalavel pelo banco de dados.

Comment: Sobre microserviços, sua adoção se deve ao fato de resolver muito bem problemas de escalabidade, resiliência, manutenção, etc. Claro que afeta performance porque tudo gira em termos de conexões de rede, mas é preferível ter uma parte do dominio nao funcionando do que te-lo inteiro derrubado porque uma simples query não funciona. Para resolver a performance, existem várias técnicas como por exemplo CQRS, event-driven, etc. Basta ter um bom design e ninguem precisa manter monoliticos extremamente performaticos a ponto de serem capazes de rodar em só uma máquina.

Answer (score 0):

A princípio entendo boa prática sim tem numa mesma coluna o cadastramento de cpf e cnpj no mesmo campo.
você criaria um cadastro único de pessoas (tanto jurídicas quanto físicas) evitando situações de duplicação desses cadastros.
Está correto também a situação de usar um campo (flag) que defina o tipo de pessoa, o que também poderia ser dispensável, se considerarmos que cpf tem 11 dígitos e cnpj tem 14. Na programação você pode diferenciar isso pelo length da variável que trouxer essa informação.

Um exemplo da boa utilidade que essa prática teria:
Suponha que uma empresa vai fazer uma compra no seu estabelecimento.
É pertinente que nessa situação esse cadastro da pessoa jurídica tenha relação com alguma pessoa física a título de representante legal.

Agora suponha que essa pessoa física já cadastrada como representante legal deseja fazer uma compra particular, sem vínculo com a pessoa jurídica que ele representa.
neste caso você já terá o cadastro dessa pessoa sem ter que ficar duplicando as informações.

Caso haja dúvida em como proceder essa vinculação do representante legal à empresa, a sugestão é criar uma tabela para essa vinculação (n pra n).
Assim, conforme o caso ou necessidade, será possível incluir vários representantes legais (pessoas físicas) para cada empresa (pessoa jurídica), bem como será possível informar uma mesma pessoa física como representante legal de várias empresas.

Além de evitar duplicações de cadastros nesses casos, quando ocorrer situações de ser necessário atualizar cadastro de uma pessoa, não será necessário ficar procurando se ele é representante legal de empresas para atualizar nesses casos também.

No geral eu sempre recomento e aplico essa prática, mas como o Maniero bem disse, cada caso deve ser analisado e feito conforme realmente for necessário e mais eficiente.