# "Herança" de tabela é uma prática ruim nesse caso?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, herança, modelo-relacional

No meu banco de dados preciso armazenar funcionários, clientes e fornecedores. Como todos esses compartilham dados em comum, porém não são todos os dados, resolvi criar uma tabela `pessoas` com as colunas em comum:

```
id // chave primária
tipo // tipo F para funcionário, C para cliente e F para fornecedor
nome
data_nascimento
endereco
inativo
```

E para armazenar os dados específicos de cada tipo fiz outras tabelas, como o `funcionarios`:

```
id_pessoa // único, não nulo e chave estrangeira em pessoa(id)
data_admissao
data_demissao
salario
```

O relacionamento entre `funcionarios` e `pessoas` deve ser de um para um (ou nenhum), já que um registro de pessoa só pode ter um registro de funcionário, de cliente ou de fornecedor.

O que tentei abordar foi uma "herança". `funcionarios` herda todas as colunas de `pessoas`.

Não sei se tomei a decisão correta aqui. Isso é uma prática ruim? Se for, existem outras alternativas? Deveria repetir todos os campos de `pessoas` em `funcionarios`, `clientes` e `fornecedores` e eliminar `pessoas`?

Devo ter me expressado mal pois esse tipo de relacionamento não parece um pra um e sim um pra um ou zero. Estou certo?

A coluna `pessoas.tipo` é realmente necessária?

Comment: Relacionado: [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/1658)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não dá para dizer que está errado, mas eu não gosto desse tipo de separação na maioria dos casos. Acho que ela é válida se o cadastro é muito grande e as partes costumam ser acessadas de forma independente na maioria das vezes. Aí funciona como uma otimização. Não que ela seja necessária e útil na maioria dos casos.

Se a pessoa só pode exercer um [papel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) na organização, então determine que ela é aquele papel, ou seja, pra que ter um cadastro de pessoa? Não há repetição alguma porque você está garantindo que ela tem só um papel. Se não há repetição, não há porque falar em [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) (leia o *link* porque é um pouco mais complicado que isto).

A maioria dos sistemas não conceitua certo e usa a abordagem de ter apenas os papéis e não as pessoas. Se uma pessoa for um funcionário e cliente ao mesmo tempo terá dois cadastros da mesma pessoa.

## Separação de [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327842/101) e da pessoa

Só que é comum a pessoa exercer mais de um papel, aí começa ser interessante ter essa separação. Então a pessoa pode se vincular a vários papeis (`tipo`) e não apenas um, como está modelado na pergunta.

Se adotar o modelo separado, pode ser interessante também ter uma forma de ligar diretamente aos cadastros específicos dos papéis. Mas é só otimização. Se for garantido que o cadastro do papel terá o mesmo `id` da pessoa, aí nem precisa porque você sabe qual é o `id` lá. Mas acho isso um pouco arriscado. Precisa saber fazer e precisa saber que não vai mudar para um dia a pessoa ter duas contas separadas em alguma tabela de papéis.

Em tese pode até eliminar o `tipo` porque tem como descobrir isso, mas exigirá mais esforço de código e de execução. Eu só não descartaria. A não ser que mantenha um código de ligação para as tabelas específicas, porque se estiver preenchido para aquele papel você sabe que ele é daquele tipo.

Respondi algumas perguntas sobre isto:

- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101)
- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Modelagem de lançamentos usando clientes e fornecedores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101)
- [Modelagem para cadastro de entidades abrangente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123492/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Isso por si só não é uma prática ruim.

No mundo de bases de dados relacionais que interagem com sistemas orientados a objetos (acredito ser o seu caso), o maior desafio de design para a base é como montar um *schema* que faça sentido e que seja fácil de manter. A discussão sobre se é melhor repetir informação ou não no banco, e o quanto repetir, trata de um assunto chamado [**normalização**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/1658).

No seu caso, você normalizou a tabela. Normalização costuma ser visto como boa prática, contanto que não seja exagerada ou desnecessária.

Eu só faria uma coisa diferente: passaria o tipo de pessoa para a tabela filha. Afinal, vai que um dia alguém se torna cliente e fornecedor ao mesmo tempo... Da forma como esta essa pessoa precisaria de duas entradas na tabela mãe.

Nos comentário o Maniero chamou a atenção a um fator importante. Como eu falei, a normalização tem suas vantagens, mas esqueci de mencionar algumas desvantagens. Dentre elas, o espalhamento de informações entre tabelas diferentes. Isso pode tornar as consultas mais custosas.

Supondo que você mantenha o modelo normalizado que propõe na pergunta. Se você quiser pesquisar, por exemplo, por um funcionário que, por exemplo:

- more em um endereço específico, e;
- receba salário dentro de determinada faixa...

Você terá que pesquisar nas duas tabelas. Um `JOIN` entre tabelas pode acabar sendo mais caro em termos de performance do que pesquisar em uma única tabela. Se a performance das pesquisas for o fator mais importante no design da base de dados - e para grandes sistemas, geralmente é - então vale a pena desnormalizar para acelerar as consultas.

Comment: Mas a tabela filha já indica o que ela é. E como vai saber em qual tabela pesquisar os dados extras? Procurar em todas possíveis?

Comment: @Maniero a lógica sobre onde pesquisar pertence à aplicação. E no exemplo na pergunta, a tabela que indica o tipo de pessoa é a tabela mãe.

Comment: Mas você acha bom pesquisar em várias tabelas só para descobrir em qual tem cadastro?

Comment: No caso do exemplo na pergunta eu só vejo necessidade de se pesquisar em uma, já que existir na filha implica em existir na mãe.

Comment: Mas se ele não sabe se é funcionário, cliente, fornecedor, banco, etc., tem que pesquisar em todas.

Comment: @Maniero Agora entendi. Se a performance de pesquisa for realmente o fator mais importante (e geralmente é), então seria melhor desnormalizar. Vou editar a resposta com relação a isso.

Comment: mas se ele for funcionário, cliente e fornecedor, **também** vai ter que pesquisar em todas do mesmo jeito, não?