# O correto seria deixar os atributos da classe abstrata como privados ou protegidos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes-abstratas

Eu não sei como eu devo deixar esses atributos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depende do que deseja. Se deixar privado a classe derivada não poderá acessá-los diretamente, em geral é o que se deseja. Se a derivada precisa acessar o campo diretamente para alguma coisa, deixe protegido. Indiretamente (através de um método protegido ou público) é claro que poderá ser acessado.

Há quem diga que o `protected` nem deveria existir na linguagem. Acho um exagero, mas dá uma indicação que ele deve ser usado com parcimônia. Muitos acham que ou a coisa é pública ou é privada. Eu prefiro ter mais granularidade. Só a experiência vai indicar quando realmente algo deve ser protegido sem causar problemas. Por isso alguns preferem nunca ter atributos protegidos. Campo privado sempre dá mais liberdade para quem desenha a classe abstrata (ou normal). O privado é detalhe de implementação. O protegido já cria um acoplamento que pode ser desnecessário ou até danoso em alguns casos.

[Não sou fã do termo atributo para isto, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9064/70).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Há também o caso em que o atributo interessa à subclasse mas você não quer que ela tenha o poder de alterar o valor do atributo. Aí você pode declarar o atributo como `protected final`. Mas à vezes não é possível porque quem define o valor inicial do atributo é a superclasse. Aí você pode deixá-lo `private`, mas disponibilizar um método `protected getAtributo()` que dá acesso somente leitura ao valor dele por parte das subclasses.

Comment: Às vezes o atributo só interessa, ou melhor só é usado, por código dentro da classe abstrata. E tem a situação que eu falei também.

Comment: E também dizer que a classe abstrata só serve para fazer herança não é muito preciso. Ela serve para fornecer uma implementação parcial que tem uso para as subclasses, mas mesmo essa implementação parcial pode ter detalhes internos que só interessam à classe abstrata. (@bigown, desculpe ter atravessado a resposta e respondido os comentários, mas o raciocínio estava na carreira aqui :-)

Comment: Mas eu gostei dos seus comentários Piovezan : /

Comment: @Piovezan que é isso, só ajudou. Pode responder tb.