# O que são Classes Abstratas

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Por que devemos usar uma classe abstrata? em qual situação? é a mesma coisa que interfaces?

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de se usar?

Comment: Também:: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89236/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89257/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139045/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113065/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101.