# Quebra de pixel criando falsa borda

Tags: html5, css3, zoom, pixels

Não sei como explicar esta situação. Criei um tooltip usando somente CSS3 e HTML5. Em tamanho normal (zoom 100%), à esquerda, os elementos ficam desfocados e dá-se a impressão de que há uma borda ao redor do tooltip (logo abaixo de "Obrigatório!", mesmo com `border: 0px; border-color: transparent;`). Já em tamanho ampliado (zoom 200%), à direita, os elementos apresentam excelente nitidez.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha teoria é de que os pixels de borda são comprimidos, o que causa esse defeito visual. Alguém sabe me dizer por que isso acontece? E como solucionar isso?

Comment: Essa setinha azul abaixo do tooltipe é um svg? Ou o "balão inteiro" é um SVG onde a seta faz parte dele?

Comment: Tanto o balão, quanto a setinha, são de CSS3 puros. Resumidamente, usei uma classe `.tooltip {position: relative;}` em uma tag `<span class="tooltip">`. Para o balão, usei `.tooltip::before{position:absolute;border:0px;border-color:transparent;}`. E para a seta, usei `.tooltip::after{position:absolute;border-color:transparent;border-top-color:transparent;}`.

Comment: Cara vc reparou que a imagem todo fica "embaçada" até o texto Administrador? Acho o problema não está relacionado com os SVGs etc... tente colocar a meta tag viewport direitinho confira as configurações do seu monitor e do browser, se for retina pode ter alguma variação... são só dicas ok. Não sei ao certo qual pode ser o problema...

Comment: Vou reformular a pergunta.

Comment: Amigo tem um tópico que já foi criado referente esse assunto, vou postar o link aqui acho que resolverá o seu problema. [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9064/como-suavizar-a-fonte-com-css-no-chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9064/como-suavizar-a-fonte-com-css-no-chrome)

Comment: Testei tudo o que tinha lá, mas não surtiu bons efeitos. Piorou tudo, na verdade. Principalmente o `shadow`, ele faz evidenciar ainda mais a divisão. Por hora, estou usando um tamanho de fonte maior, o que "resolveu" o problema.